# Archive only reaches back to around mid 2012

Tags: facebook, facebook-archive

Facebook has an option to download an archive of all your information. It takes some time to do this but after Facebook ends, they send you an email with a .zip file that has all your information. I'm interested in the Messages, but they're not complete, they're not the full history, it only goes so far (around mid 2012). It might be that this is deliberate, but it's supposed to have ALL the complete information. Any help would be appreciated as to how to download all the conversations

Edit:
I've tried the zip process, manually going to the top (same), a Facebook app (MessageSaver), a Facebook add-on and an Android app. They all return the same number of messages.

Comment: Every one except the script, because I dont think it would work, because going all the way up I can only see the conversation up to a date(about 18085 messages) while logged on the website manually. But I've tried the archive option, the m.facebook.com option and the hack option, also the rest of manual options

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, I'll add it as an Edit. I did that process three times and it doesn't return all the information(from almost all conversations)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue as you. I believe Facebook is not taking the appropriate action to resolve this issue. If you're interested in helping me escalate this to Facebook, could you sign up your email here: https://upscri.be/550d9d/ ? I'm open to other ways of escalating the issue, but I was thinking of writing a blog post and tweeting at Facebook, would be good to join forces.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/405183566203254?helpref=faq_content) the data may not be absolutely everything from  inception:

> We store different categories of data for different time periods, so you may not find all of your data since you joined Facebook. You will not find information or content that you have deleted because this is deleted from Facebook servers.